# How do you convert the quotient of a division of two polynomials to a standard polynomial instead of a tuple in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am creating a program to predict GDP per capita in Python and I have two models - one for GDP and the other for population. To create a model for GDP per capita I simply divided the two polynomials. However, I got something out of the ordinary:

```
(poly1d([-109498.08669488]),
 poly1d([-2.73247119e+06,  2.17471159e+10, -6.49022312e+13,  8.60827452e+16,
        -4.28139449e+19]))
```

Is there any way to convert this to a normal polynomial? What I mean by normal is something like this:

```
4x^5 + 3x^4 + 2x^3 + x^2 + 5x + 9
```

Comment: Take one of them. Obviously, one of them is quotient and the other is remainder.

Comment: @MechanicPig The thing is I need both.

Comment: If you `print` a tuple, as you probably did here, you get the `repr` of each item. Print each of them separately.

Comment: How do you want to use them? You didn't explain it in the question. @MathGeek

Comment: @MechanicPig I need to create a model for GDP per capita that is as accurate as possible. This means that I will need the quotient as well as the remainder. Is there a way I can format both of them together into one normal polynomial?